Are Mathematicals Subject to Potency and Act
Are mathematicals subject to potency and act? What prompted me to ask this question is the following: Now matter is the principle of individuation not only in singular things but also in the objects of mathematics; for there are two kinds of matter, one sensible and the other intelligible. And by sensible matter is meant such things as bronze and wood, or any changeable matter, such as fire and water and all things of this sort; and singular sensible things are individuated by such matter. But by intelligible matter is meant what exists in things which are sensible but are not viewed as sensible, as the objects of mathematics. For just as the form of man exists in such and such Matter, which is an organic body, in a similar way the form of a circle or of a triangle exists in this matter, which is a continuum, whether surface or solid (Commentary on the Metaphysics 8:10).

In the qoute above Thomas speaks about the technical term "form". Why do you think that the passage refers to the technical terms "act" and "potency"?

In a previous post today you were just reminded by Lagrange that the transcendental relation perdures even when the term disappears in contrast to the everyday predicamental relation. In Aristotelian philosophy pure mathematicals are individuated by their contimuum intelligible matter which isn't changeable and won't disappear at least in the Platonic sense, so mathematicals transcend those always changing predicamental entities defined out of their respective domains of discourse as pure passive act w/o potency. Of course non-Platonically speaking they may have potency to human's knowledge...
